# Looking for a way to manually increment the WordPress post ID

Tags: wordpress

I recently created a staging site to redesign an eCommerce website. Before pushing staging live, I imported all of the customers and orders into the staging site then went live. The issue that I'm running into is that the client's CRM is using the post ID for order tracking. The redesigned site's post ID for newly created orders is about 5,000 behind where the old site's post ID counter was. This is resulting in duplicate content issues in the client's CRM.

Is there a way to manually increment the post ID counter to a higher value?

Comment: Usually even when you delete a post the ID won't be used ever again and the count keeps going up. Have you tried adding a post via `phpmyadmin` and manually changing the ID there ?

Comment: The posts were never deleted. They simply didn't exist on the staging site as the live site had gotten considerably further ahead before staging was pushed live.

Answer (score 0):

A fellow developer helped me with the following code:

ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT = x

Run this in phpMyAdmin to change the counter number to whatever value you place in x. Just make sure that it's higher than your current highest post number or serious issues can arise.

Answer (score 0):

The code below would set the post id at 10000:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

Value has to be higher than your current highest post number.

More info here:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-reset-product-id/#post-14207045
Please note that the "wp_post_meta" table name is wrong in this article. The correct is "wp_postmeta".